# replace character at certain position inside javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

if I have string inside javascript function like

```
function someFunction(){
   var myStr = "12345678911";
   var maskedStr = "";       
}
```

how can I use myStr values with * to maskedStr contain string like

```
var maskedStr = "1234567*91*";
```

Comment: What are the possible lengths for `myStr` and how are those handled?

Answer (score 0):

```
function someFunction(){
   var myStr = "12345678911";
   var maskedStr = myStr.replace("9", "*");       
}
```

Comment: this replace only on index 9?